# Data ID Jquery Hover Image overlay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I hope you all are doing great,
I was working on this personal project and Im stuck at the very last bit so basically I have these anchor links which take me to another page but to give the user a short preview I want to display a image on hover of the anchor tag

Index.html

```html
  <div class="image-preview"  style="position: fixed; pointer-events: none;">
      <img src="images/icon/icon.png" class="imgprecont" style="float: right; width: 30%;">
  </div>
    <a href="#" data-img="images/1.png" class="prj">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="images/2.png" class="prj">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="images/3.png" class="prj">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="images/4.png" class="prj">4/a>
    <a href="#" data-img="images/5.png" class="prj">5</a>
```

APP.js

```
//PRJ Preview
let prj = $('.prj')
prj.each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover( function() {
        let imgcont = $('imgprecont')
        let prjimg = $('.prj').data('img')
        imgcont.src = prjimg;
        console.log(prjimg)
    })
})
```

So the current problem here is the app is not able to change the source of the image and when I hover over the link the console log shows me data-id for the first link and not the others which is  ***images/1.png***

Any help is appreciated thanks!

The project is build in JQuery by the way

Comment: I guess also `$('.prj').data('img')` should be `$(this).data('img')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 issues with your code. You are using the wrong class selector. it should be `$('.imgprecont')` and not `$('imgprecont')`. And you need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.prj')`.

Please find the working example below. Please note, I have used random images for demonstration.

```js
//PRJ Preview
let prj = $('.prj')
prj.each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover( function() {
        let imgcont = $('.imgprecont')
        let prjimg = $(this).data('img')
        $('.imgprecont').attr('src', prjimg);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-preview"  style="position: fixed; pointer-events: none;">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/620/536/354.jpg?hmac=_2pm-B21Zzjfs_NH_75cY2sC0odhWQbKUMU9oCHoyh4" class="imgprecont" style="float: right; width: 30%;">
  </div>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/620/536/354.jpg?hmac=_2pm-B21Zzjfs_NH_75cY2sC0odhWQbKUMU9oCHoyh4" class="prj">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU7_x9EBQVhvT5aRr0" class="prj">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1084/536/354.jpg?grayscale&hmac=Ux7nzg19e1q35mlUVZjhCLxqkR30cC-CarVg-nlIf60" class="prj">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1060/536/354.jpg?blur=2&hmac=0zJLs1ar00sBbW5Ahd_4zA6pgZqCVavwuHToO6VtcYY" class="prj">4/a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/620/536/354.jpg?hmac=_2pm-B21Zzjfs_NH_75cY2sC0odhWQbKUMU9oCHoyh4" class="prj">5</a>
```

Comment: Except from that you point those things that has already been said in comments, then you can improve the answer by saying: Remove .each, replace `$(this).mouseover` with `$('.prj').mouseover`

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I was focussing on my answer and I saw comments later on.

Comment: THANKS alot and my bad I didnt notice the problem there! TY